# [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] Next-Auth.js error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

So I had my sessions working and my login working just fine. I don't remember changing a thing. Then randomly, for whatever reason, I get the [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] error.

The full error on the server is this:

```
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error fetch failed {
  error: {
    message: 'fetch failed',
    stack: 'TypeError: fetch failed\n' +
      '    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5555:34)\n' +
      '    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5877:42\n' +
      '    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7\n' +
      '    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)\n' +
      '    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)\n' +
      '    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)',
    name: 'TypeError'
  },
  url: 'https://website.co.uk/api/auth/session',
  message: 'fetch failed'
}
```

I changed the website name as I do not want people to navigate to it. I require the website to be behind a SSH connection for some other stuff to work. I do not seem to be able to fix this error and I do not see what I am doing wrong.

I will include all the relevent pages and files, and hopefully someone can see what I am doing wrong.

**login.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { signIn, getSession } from 'next-auth/react'
import styles from '../styles/Login.module.css'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Head from 'next/head'

export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const session = await getSession(context)
  if (session) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/'
      }
    }
  }
  return {
    props: {session}
  }
}

function Login({ session }) {

  const handleSignIn = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    signIn('discord')
  }

  console.log(session)

  
  return (
    <div className={styles.body}>
        <Head>
          <title>Noodleworld Login</title>
          <link href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/minecraft-4" rel="stylesheet">
          </link>
        </Head>
        <div className={styles.loginwrap}>

            <h1 className={styles.title}>NoodleWorld Minecraft Server</h1>
            <h2>Login with discord</h2>

            <Image
                src={'https://i.imgur.com/MEU6cIv.png'}
                alt='Discord-logo'
                width='50'
                height='50'
                >
            </Image>
            <div className={styles.image_border}>
                <Image
                    className={styles.image}
                    src={'https://i.imgur.com/xLdvcfF.png'}
                    alt='Discord-logo'
                    width='200'
                    height='40'
                    onClick={handleSignIn}>
                </Image>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
  )
}

export default Login
```

**.env file**

```
DISCORD_CLIENT_ID=string
DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET=string

NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY=string
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY=string

JWT_SECRET=string

NEXTAUTH_URL=https://website.co.uk
```

**[...nextauth].js file**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import DiscordProvider from 'next-auth/providers/discord'

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        DiscordProvider({
            clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET
          })
    ], 
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
            // Persist the OAuth access_token and or the user id to the token right after signin
            if (account) {
              token.accessToken = account.access_token
              token.id = profile.id
            }
            return token
        },
        async session({ session, token, user }) {
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken
            session.user.id = token.id

            return session
        }
        
        
    }
})
```

That is every file I can find that affects anything.

All I can tell is that the session API endpoint for the session, I.E  the https://website.co.uk/api/auth/session works when signed in, and is accessable, but will not return the session. I am very new at this and I could and most likely am way off. any help would be appreciated

I have tried most common things like checking the .env file for the NEXTAUTH_URL, but that is normal from what I can tell. Other than that, I am stumped.